# grab value from string in reverse order

Tags: c#, .net

I have file with txt content inside. Content is generated dynamicly and I want to read in reverse order, from end of file to the first matched semicolon, for example:

```
sad12e1sadsadsadasdasd12e2q3312sdadasdasdasqe21231122123123asd1asda;123456
```

so I want to grab this `123456` integer, ofcourse this is generated content with random int length.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have always the searched text at the end of the string and after a semicolon you could use

```
string.LastIndexOf(';');
```

for example

```
string test = "sad12e1sadsadsadasdasd12e2q3312sdadasdasdasqe21231122123123asd1asda;123456";
int pos = test.LastIndexOf(';');
if(pos >= 0)
   string myText = test.Substring(pos+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

What @Steve said, or just

```
string value = "sad12e1sadsadsadasdasd12e2q3312sdadasdasdasqe21231122123123asd1asda;123456";
string number = value.Split(';')[1];
```

though this doesn't handle the case where a semi-colon is missing.

Comment: semicolon will always be present, so it's ok.

Comment: It also doesn't handle the case where there are multiple semicolons.

Comment: edge case @panjo. always expect things to happen that should never happen

Comment: True, @zimdanen, it doesn't.